# passing the signed_request in external website?

Tags: php, facebook

So heres the problem.

I do have the $_REQUEST['signed_request'] just after the login on facebook, which is great, but i would like to pass it to another page, so i can keep the authorization and information.

My application isnt a canvas page but an external website. Coded in PHP.

Any help?

Comment: can't really see what is the problem, if you wan to save the request just save it, and retrieve it when you need it

Comment: How can i save it? i will use it so i can get the $session variable and post on user wall

Comment: show some of your code and we can help you better

Comment: how did you get a signed_request when you're outside facebook?

Comment: The FB [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) uses sessions for this purpose, I suggest you review the code and use similar approach if you are not willing to use the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how long you want to save it for, if it's just for the time the user is on the page you can save it in your session variables:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['signature'] = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
```

now as long as you have a session you can retrieve this data, even if you navigate to different pages.

```
$variable = $_SESSION['signature'];
```

if you want more details, maybe you should show some of your code, and what you have so far